# Arduino: write a pointer to a char in a file

Tags: arrays, arduino, buffer, arduino-c++

I have this array,

```
char *buffer = (char *) calloc(size, 1);
```

How can write it into an SD card file? I used `f.write(buffer, size);`, but I got on this error:

> invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: arduino is not `C` only C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast in C++:

```
f.write((uint8_t *)buffer, size);
```

BTW, never use `calloc` or `malloc` on Arduino or any other  low resources machine. The main problem is that the heap will fragment very quickly and eventually you will not have any memory available for allocation even if the free heap memory will be larger than the requested amount. If you need to use dynamic allocation read about [memory pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool)

Comment: Re *"never use calloc or malloc on Arduino"*: Perhaps explain ***why*** in the answer (and/or link to a place where it is explained)? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).